# Spring Security 6 - exclude some urls with the means other than securityFilterChain configuration

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security and trying to figure out if something I want is possible at all. So far it's not according to my research. My application is a small blog platform which I write entirely for testing purposes, hence some approaches might not be production ready.

I have the following config:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/users").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable());

        return http.build();
    }
```

`POST /api/v1/users` is excluded because I use thing endpoint to create a user, hence anyone should be able to access it. However I want some other endpoints to be excluded from the config, for example `GET /api/v1/posts` which returns all posts on the platform.

The same thing is with comments, `GET /api/v1/posts/{postId}/comments` should be available to unregistered users.

What I don't want is to add every such URL to the securityFilterChain, is there any way to achieve that with an annotation on top of the controller method? I tried something like `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")` but apparently interceptors kick in after authentication and I still get 401.